# Enable "progress plain" in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-buildkit

When I run a build using `docker-compose build --progress plain`, it shows more useful information during the build than the default BuildKit output.

Is there a way to embed the plain progress option into the docker-compose.yml file itself so I can just call `docker-compose build` and still get the better output?

I tried adding these build args, but none of them seemed to work:

```
build:
    args:
        #progress: plain  
        #- progress=plain  
        #- progress plain  
        #BUILDKIT_PROGRESS: plain  
        #- BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though it seems like it ought to be possible looking at the current implementation of `docker-compose`, notably [the `_CLIBuilder`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/service.py#L1848) which is [invoked](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/service.py#L1110) over the services dict's [`build` method](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/service.py#L1089).

However, *no such similarly-named key exists* in the [configuration schema](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/config/config_schema_v1.json).

So it appears that *you can't*, at least not yet.

Incidentally, from the above, I'd expect to eventually find it here

```
services:
    build:
        progress: plain
```

rather than the `args:` child key.

Comment: My workaround is to have docker-compose.yml reference the image `image: image-name` rather than doing `build` as part of compose. Then use a wrapper script that calls `docker build --progress plain -t image-name && docker-compose up`

Comment: Just in case, currently, it still returns: `services.app.build Additional property progress is not allowed`.

Answer (score 64):

Where you don't want to disable buildkit, one can use

```
BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain docker compose build
# or
BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain docker-compose build
```

or without buildkit which serves plain progress by default

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker compose build
# or
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker-compose build
```

*using docker desktop 20.10.8 + docker-compose 2.0.1*

Comment: This works for me! Last comment I had the same issue than @Artfaith `services.app.build Additional property progress is not allowed`

Comment: This works in macOS in 2024 as well!

Answer (score 6):

For Compose V2. Refer to: [Compose V2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/migrate/)

Here is command originally shared by hasnat but modified to ComposeV2:

```
BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain docker compose build
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently it is not possible using compose file, but if you need it to be done always like this, you can write a wrapper:

```
docker-compose(){
        echo "[WARNING] runnig wrapper docker-compose..."
        if [ "$1" == "build" ]; then
            /usr/local/bin/docker-compose $@ --progress plain
        else
            /usr/local/bin/docker-compose $@
        fi
}
```

add this code to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`

then you can use it as usual

** remember source your profile after edit

Answer (score -3):

It seems the `docker-compose.yaml` accepts an `args` field:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  main:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: se/Dockerfile
      args:
        progress: plain
```