# how to save the logs for docker-compose up -d --build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The logs are printed on the console when I do `docker-compose up -d --build`, how can I have them saved to a file so I can go through the logs?

These logs

```
0.0s  => => transferring dockerfile: 771B                                                                            
0.0s  => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                               
0.0s  => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                 
0.0s  => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8.12-bullseye                                       
1.5s  => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                   
0.0s  => [internal] load build context                                                                               
2.0s  => => transferring context: 847.24kB                                                                           
1.9s  => [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8.12-bullseye@sha256:b39ab988ac2fa749273cf6fdeb89fb3635850824419dc61  
0.0s  => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.8.12-bullseye@sha256:b39ab988ac2fa749273cf6fdeb89fb3635850824419dc61  
0.0s  =>   CACHED [2/7] WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker already saves the logs in a json file. To find it you can do

```
docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' [container id]
```

Or if you just want the outputs of the docker logs function just do this :

```
docker-compose logs --no-color > logs.txt
```

For docker-compose up --build, did you try that :

```
docker-compose up --build &> logs.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this together, but my question is on the `docker-compose build logs` while it is building, not the output of the actual container.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved using `docker-compose build` and the `--progress` flag and specifying one of the following options: auto, tty, plain, or quiet (default "auto")

So to persist the logs in your terminal you would build with:

`docker-compose build --progress plain`

See `--help`:

```
 $ docker-compose build --help

Usage:  docker compose build [OPTIONS] [SERVICE...]

Build or rebuild services

Options:
      --build-arg stringArray   Set build-time variables for services.
      --no-cache                Do not use cache when building the image
      --progress string         Set type of progress output (auto, tty, plain, quiet) (default "auto")
      --pull                    Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image.
  -q, --quiet                   Don't print anything to STDOUT
      --ssh string              Set SSH authentications used when building service images. (use
                                'default' for using your default SSH Agent)
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a different answer, the `--progress` flag works if you are doing a `docker compose build`.

But in your question, you are doing `docker compose up`, where `--progress` doesn't work.   In that case, to get full plain text output to the terminal do something this:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker compose up -d --build
```

Source:  [Enable "progress plain" in docker-compose file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537349/enable-progress-plain-in-docker-compose-file)